# How to handle JPA CollectionTable with Inheritance?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have to create a hierarchy of classes where a superclass has a `@CollectionTable` representing a map. I tried to implement it but it works only with one child class.

I want to do the following. I have the current structure on the left, and the desired structure on the right.
[image: UML diagram of the structure]

The stable (working) code looks like this:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Animal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
}

@Entity(name = "cats")
@Audited
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = Cat.PET_TYPE)
public abstract class Cat extends Animal {
    public static final String PET_TYPE = "C";

    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    @Column(name = "value")
    @CollectionTable(name = "cat_properties", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cat_id"))
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
}

@Audited
@Entity(name = "persiancats")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = PersianCat.PERSIAN_CAT_TYPE)
public class PersianCat extends Cat {
    public static final String PERSIAN_CAT_TYPE = "P";
}
```

This is how I tried to achieve the modification:

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Animal {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;
}

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class Pet extends Animal {
    @ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @MapKeyColumn(name = "name")
    @Column(name = "value")
    @CollectionTable(name = "pet_properties", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "pet_id"))
    private Map<String, String> properties = new HashMap<>();
}

@Entity(name = "cats")
@Audited
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.CHAR)
@DiscriminatorValue(value = Cat.PET_TYPE)
public class Cat extends Pet {
    public static final String PET_TYPE = "C";
}

@Entity(name = "dogs")
@Audited
public class Dog extends Pet {
}

@Audited
@Entity(name = "persiancats")
@DiscriminatorValue(value = PersianCat.PERSIAN_CAT_TYPE)
public class PersianCat extends Pet {
    public static final String PERSIAN_CAT_TYPE = "P";
}
```

Hibernate creates the `pet_properties` table but it only references either `dogs` or `cats`. My intention was to **create a common table** for both dog and cat (and persiancat) properties.

What am I missing or doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you're trying to achieve is logically impossible, and here's why (I stumbled upon the same problem, although in another domain). To reference a  table from your `pet_properties` table Hibernate creates a foreign key from `pet_properties` to the target table (dogs or cats in your case). A foreign key essentially means *to every entry in this table should correspond an entry from another table*, and that *another table* is only one table. Therefore, if you said that your `pet_properties` entry references both `dogs` and `cats` tables, then it will immediately break the foreign key properties, because if it references dogs, then it doesn't reference cats, and vice versa.

So the auto-generated option that Hibernate gave you (separate tables `dogs_properties` and `cats_properties`) seems to be the correct way.

Answer (score 0):

After I removed this `@CollectionTable(name = "cat_properties", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "cat_id"))` line, Hibernate created two tables, one called cats_properties (for cats and persiancats) and one called dogs_properties. This is not entirely what I was looking for, which was a common table for both entities, but it is acceptable.

Comment: pretty much same issue.. have you found another solution? I can't create more tables as they would be like 10